# How to handle timed tests

Tags: interviewing

When looking for jobs, I sometimes get timed coding challenges, such as on Codility. I have never been good at tests with relatively short duration (2 hours or less): they often leave me flustered and result in me hacking something out quickly that is hardly ideal or just wrong. I like to take time to consider a problem and its edge cases, prototype an idea, test it, refactor it to be readable and maintainable, and so on. I must do all of this much quicker in these tests.

I can handle tests that are very short (like FizzBuzz) or that give me more time to think (even 3 hours is fine) well enough, but I cannot seem to handle timed coding challenges with any consistent rate of success. If it was feasible, I would ask for the former types of tests but I doubt that would be fair to other applicants.

Regardless, I wish to be more consistent. I understand I can practise these types of challenges and whatnot, and I do, but I do not think that is precisely my problem. Often I will realise a (better) solution not long after the time has run out or after calming down. I believe I am thinking too much or overanalysing. So, my question is:

- Is there a thought process one can employ to these timed coding challenges that lets you think quickly?

Comment: *they often leave me flustered and result in me hacking something out quickly that is hardly ideal or just wrong.* : Some tests are designed so that you cannot finish them properly. Either you do a part of them cleanly, or all of them at a draft-level. Comparing your results to the results of someone of an equivalent skill level could give you a better understanding of this.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Would doing them all at a draft-level be a better idea for tests that are automatically graded? For example, If I have three tasks, and do one cleanly, but cannot do the other two quick enough, it may look badly if my grade is 100 out of 300. I suppose it depends on who is looking at it.

Comment: I question the value of such tests personally. I've been writing software for decades and I still bomb on timed tests. The simple fact is that not everyone thinks the same way. For me, I need some time to ponder, as you do. For everyone, it's not just a task to be done. For some, it's almost like art, because I'm creating. I do them and I bomb them and they don't call me back. NBD. I question the judgement of anyone who thinks that's how you can tell a good developer any. As I've been doing this for 30 years, I think my question is a valid one.

Comment: Treat it like any other deadline. Implement core function first implement enough of the non-core function to document plans for that and permit you to move forward efficiently. Don't get hung up on perfecting/optimizing before function is there (though you can and should document ideas for that) Paraphrasing the estimable Steve Boies: "Make it work, make it good, make it great. In that order."

Comment: If the tests are automated, I think you should look elsewhere for work. Unless they are hiring machines, that is.

Comment: The only way to become better is to do more of these tests.  Practice should reduce anxiety and allow you to concentrate better.  You will also get familiar with the actual problems and their solutions.

Comment: Try to set up your practice environment to simulate the expected testing environment. For example, if you are not allowed to use on-line references during the test, practice without them, too. If the test environment does not include interactive debugging, do your practice sessions without an interactive debugger, etc. For practice, give yourself a slightly lesser time limit (say, 90 minutes). Then, the 2 hour limit for the "real" test will seem longer in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of references that might be of use.

The answer can be condensed I believe into doing what you can **well** in the time allotted, and not to get too stressed about it.  It is impossible to practice effectively IMHO for these types of timed tests -- either you know enough of the material the interviewer is after or you don't.

> How to Take Timed Tests Without Stress

[Reference one](http://www.visualspatial.org/files/timedtest.pdf)

> The Dreaded Timed Test Alexandra “Allie” Golon

[Reference two](http://classroom.synonym.com/timed-tests-stress-5656116.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the best way to get better at dealing with timed tests and stress is to practice. Start small, make goals and a regular schedule.